# vmware player host not accessible once vmware player is running

Tags: vmware-player

Once the vmware player on the host machine is started the host appears to not be accessible on the lan ie folder shares , ping , microsoft sql server but the vm running in vmware player has all of these accessible . What could be the issue ?

Comment: the irony is the host machine and virtual machine are both accessible via remote desktop

Comment: Is your host connected via wifi?

Comment: the host is on cable and the network is bridged . host ip 192.168.10.4 vm 192.168.10.20

Comment: OK well, there goes what I was about to suggest. I've read that some wireless routers have issues when you try to connect a host and guest bridged together and attempting to access the network at the same time.

Comment: its not that its the first time i have installed the vm . it was working fine all week long it just broke down today morning . I have troubleshooted it uninstalled the vm , disabled the firewall , disabled the antivirus still it won't respond.

Comment: Wanted to uninstall the network driver and reinstall tomorrow i can access the machine remotely but require physically to be there to reinstall the Nic card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled the VM player. Removed the VM ware NAT and Host Only Nic . Installed VM ware station pro with volume license. Disabled the firewall . Restated both host and VM multiple times . And it works now able to ping host to vm and vm to host all accessible via the network.